# JSON decode in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, arraylist

How can I retrieve value from this JSON in android?
I want to create an ArrayList. I've tried **JSONObject** to access the value. But It need to create object for every city. I want to access all city using a loop inside it like as follows.

```
{
    "City A": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": 9.96233,
            "Latitude": 49.80404
        }
    },
    "City B": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": 6.11499,
            "Latitude": 50.76891
        }
    },
    "City C": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": 6.80592,
            "Latitude": 51.53548
        }
    },
    "City D": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": 9.50523,
            "Latitude": 51.31991
        }
    },
    "City E": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": 9.66089,
            "Latitude": 48.70158
        }
    },
    "City F": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": 9.93368,
            "Latitude": 53.55608
        }
    },
    "City G": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": 11.56122,
            "Latitude": 48.14496
        }
    },
    "City H": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": 13.34253,
            "Latitude": 52.5319
        }
    },
    "City I": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": 6.11327,
            "Latitude": 50.77715
        }
    },
    "City J": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": 13.36671,
            "Latitude": 52.54344
        }
    }
}
```

How can I manage this when I want the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

**City.java** *(model class)*

```
public class City implements Comparable {
    private String name; // The name of the city
    private double latitude; // its latitude
    private double longitude; // its longitude

    public City(String name, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.name = name;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ": " + latitude + " - " + longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object c) {
        City city = (City) c;
        return name.compareTo(city.name);
    }
}
```

**App.java:**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Your JSON string
        String jsonString = "{\"City A\":{\"Position\":{\"Longitude\":9.96233,\"Latitude\":49.80404}},\"City B\":{\"Position\":{\"Longitude\":6.11499,\"Latitude\":50.76891}},\"City C\":{\"Position\":{\"Longitude\":6.80592,\"Latitude\":51.53548}},\"City D\":{\"Position\":{\"Longitude\":9.50523,\"Latitude\":51.31991}},\"City E\":{\"Position\":{\"Longitude\":9.66089,\"Latitude\":48.70158}},\"City F\":{\"Position\":{\"Longitude\":9.93368,\"Latitude\":53.55608}},\"City G\":{\"Position\":{\"Longitude\":11.56122,\"Latitude\":48.14496}},\"City H\":{\"Position\":{\"Longitude\":13.34253,\"Latitude\":52.5319}},\"City I\":{\"Position\":{\"Longitude\":6.11327,\"Latitude\":50.77715}},\"City J\":{\"Position\":{\"Longitude\":13.36671,\"Latitude\":52.54344}}}";
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>(); // The arraylist that will hold the cities

        // A JSON array with the the names of all the cities
        JSONArray cityNames = jsonObj.names();

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
            String cityName = cityNames.getString(i);
            JSONObject jsonCity = jsonObj.getJSONObject(cityName);
            JSONObject jsonPosition = jsonCity.getJSONObject("Position");

            cities.add(new City(cityName, jsonPosition.getDouble("Latitude"), jsonPosition.getDouble("Longitude")));
        }

        Collections.sort(cities); // Sort the cities' arraylist by city name
        cities.forEach(System.out::println); // Print the cities
    }

}
```

*Output:*

```
City A: 49.80404 - 9.96233
City B: 50.76891 - 6.11499
City C: 51.53548 - 6.80592
City D: 51.31991 - 9.50523
City E: 48.70158 - 9.66089
City F: 53.55608 - 9.93368
City G: 48.14496 - 11.56122
City H: 52.5319 - 13.34253
City I: 50.77715 - 6.11327
City J: 52.54344 - 13.36671
```

Comment: To work with code response should be in JsonArray. Its JsonObject.

Comment: The **OP** clearly stated that he is using a container `JSONObject`, not a `JSONArray`.

Comment: cityNames JSONArray only hold until "City G". I cannot access in later city

Comment: @Shanto it works just fine for me. Notice that the array is not ordered yet. Are you getting a correct output at the end ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice. It works fine. Thank You Sparta

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google gson to convert string to Java object.

Answer (score -1):

TO get Data with for loop you should have JSONArray.
This is response you should use.
Then using this code you can apply for loop and List or ArrayList to save data.

```
[{
    "city_name": "City A",
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 9.96233,
        "Latitude": 49.80404
    }
}, {
    "city_name": "City B",
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 6.11499,
        "Latitude": 50.76891
    }
 }, {
    "city_name": "City C",
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 6.80592,
        "Latitude": 51.53548
    }
 }, {
    "city_name": "City D",
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 9.50523,
        "Latitude": 51.31991
    }
}, {
    "city_name": "City E",
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 9.66089,
        "Latitude": 48.70158
    }
}, {
    "city_name": "City F",
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 9.93368,
        "Latitude": 53.55608
    }
}, {
    "city_name": "City G",
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 11.56122,
        "Latitude": 48.14496
    }
}, {
    "city_name": "City H",
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 13.34253,
        "Latitude": 52.5319
    }
}, {
    "city_name": "City I",
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 6.11327,
        "Latitude": 50.77715
    }
}, {
    "city_name": "City J",
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 13.36671,
        "Latitude": 52.54344
    }
}]
```

then Java code as:

```
JSONArray json_array= new JSONArray(responseString);

for(int i= 0; i<json_array.length(); i++){
   JSONObject json_object = json_array.get(i);
   String cityname=json_object.getString("city_name");
   JSONObject json_object_position = json_object.getJSONObject("Position");
   long longitude=json_object_position.getString("Longitude");
   long latitude=json_object_position.getString("Latitude");
   // Save the data in List you want.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `names()` method of  JSONObject.
Try this :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourjsonString);
JSONArray jarray = jsonObject.names();

for(int i= 0; i<jarray.length(); i++){
  String name = jarray.getString(i);
}
```